# Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently running into a problem with an `UPDATE` query. What I'm trying to run is:

```
dbquery("UPDATE users SET vip_points = 'vip_points' +'". $points ."' WHERE username = '". $user ."'");
```

`$user` and `$points` are sent via a form. I've tried echoing the results and they come out to what I post.

Database error

> Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'vip_points'

So can some one please explain what's wrong with my query? It's worked on other MySQL servers. At the moment I'm using MySQL server 5.5 under Windows 2008.

Oh, and `vip_points` column is set as 0 by default.

Thanks.

Comment: [1] You forgot to say what are the values of `$points` and `$user`. [2] **NEVER EVER** send a query that contains values straight from a `<form>` inside. Google "PHP SQL injection" to find out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quoting values you shouldn't be quoting. Try this:

```
dbquery("UPDATE users SET vip_points = vip_points + ". ... ." where username = '". $user ."'");
```

Comment: this is your answer, also the single quotes around $points are not needed as long as it's an integer value. (use `(int)$points` for that)

Comment: Apologies. And the post is filtered with a built-in CMS filter function and mysql_real_escape_string. This is also in the administrator panel and not public. Once I've learnt more I plan to do pre-prepared queries. The values of $user is obviously a username, and vip points a number.